# ViewModel Delete Concurrency Excecption Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, concurrency, viewmodel

I am working on catching concurrency exceptions.  I am able to catch the concurrency exceptions when a user edits the data fine.  I am having trouble catching the exception when a user deletes data.

On my **Index** page, I have a button to delete each **Vehicle** object.  Pressing that button does a **Post** to the Delete action.  Here is the Delete action:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(VehicleIndexViewModel vehicleIndexViewModel)
{
  try
  {
    Vehicle vehicle = db.Vehicles.Find(vehicleIndexViewModel.VehicleID);
    //To test for concurrency errors
    //vehicle.Timestamp = vehicleIndexViewModel.Timestamp;  

    db.Entry(vehicle).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
  {
    return RedirectToAction("Index", 
      new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary{{"concurrencyError", true }});
  }
  catch (DataException)
  {
    //Log the error (add a variable name after Exception)
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The system was unable to delete that" 
      + " vehicle. Try again, and if the problem persists"
      + " contact your system administrator.");
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
}
```

No matter what, the user should be redirected to the Index page. Here is the Index page's **Get** action:

```
public ViewResult Index(bool? concurrencyError)
{
  if (concurrencyError.GetValueOrDefault())
  {
    ViewBag.ConcurrencyErrorMessage = "The record you attempted to delete "
      + "was modified by another user after you got the original values. "
      + "The delete operation was canceled and the current values in the "
      + "database have been displayed. If you still want to delete this "
      + "record, click the Delete button again. Otherwise "
      + "click the Back to List hyperlink.";
  }

  IEnumerable<Vehicle> vehicles = db.Vehicles.Include(v => v.VehicleType);

  IEnumerable<VehicleIndexViewModel> viewModel 
    = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Vehicle>, 
                 IEnumerable<VehicleIndexViewModel>>(vehicles);

  return View(viewModel);
}
```

The code never catches the concurrency error.  I test by opening the index page twice.  On one of the pages, I open the edit page of a vehicle and change something.  Once that's saved, I go back to the other page and click "Delete."  **The Delete action fires, and the vehicle is deleted, but the concurrency error is not caught.**  You can see where I commented out vehicle.Timestamp = vehicleIndexViewModel.Timestamp;.  I thought putting the value of the viewModel back into the actual would raise the error, but it doesn't work that way either.

I'm sure there's just something I don't understand, but what am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT

---

Erik Philips found the logic error that I had, but there was another issue that I ran into right away.  My ViewModel was not returning the Timestamp data.  In fact, the only data it was returning was the VehicleID.

When I tried to add a hidden field to the form, I would get an error.  The code just below this would not work:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Timestamp" value="@item"/>
```

The Timestamp field needs to be a valid Base-64 string.  The error you will get is:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than >two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.

This is how I ended up storing the Timestamp value on the view:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Timestamp" value="@Convert.ToBase64String(item.Timestamp)"/>
```

So, my whole Html.BeginForm looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Vehicle",  FormMethod.Post, null))
{                                        
    <input type="hidden" name="VehicleID" value="@item.VehicleID"/>  
    <input type="hidden" name="VehicleName" value="@item.VehicleName"/> 
    <input type="hidden" name="Timestamp" value="@Convert.ToBase64String(item.Timestamp)"/>                                
    <input type="image" src="../../Content/Images/Delete.gif" value="Delete" name="deletevehicle @item.VehicleID" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete @item.VehicleName.Replace("'", "").Replace("\"", "")?');"/>  
}
```

Although, I really didn't need to put VehicleName in a hidden field.

Once that was done, all I needed to do was use AutoMapper to map the values back into a vehicle object, set the EntityState to Deleted, and try to SaveChanges;

```
try
{
    Vehicle vehicle = Mapper.Map<VehicleIndexViewModel, Vehicle>(vehicleIndexViewModel);
    db.Entry(vehicle).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary { { "concurrencyError", true } });
}
```

That's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I see would happen if these events happened in this order:

**User 1**

> Vehicle/Edit VehicleID=1 (Timestamp =1)

**User 2**

> Vehicle/Edit VehicleID=1 (Timestamp =1)

**User 1**

> Vehicle/Update VehicleID=1, Title="Some Text", (Timestamp=2)

**User2**

> Vehicle/DeleteConfirmed VehicleID=1, Timestamp =1

```
/* DeleteConfirmed */

// Default Model Binder 
VehicleIndexViewModel.VehicleID = 1
VehicleIndexViewModel.Timestamp = 1

Vehicle vehicle = db.Vehicles.Find(vehicleIndexViewModel.VehicleID);
//vehicle.VehicleID = 1
//vehicle.Timestamp = 2

// Set to Delete
db.Entry(vehicle).State = EntityState.Deleted;

// Delete in database
db.SaveChanges();
```

Basically all you're doing is retrieve the Vehicle in it's current state (updated from user 1) and deleting it.  Unless, by some freak chance, someone did an update between `Find` and `SaveChanges` there will never be a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`.

What I believe you can do instead would be to [Attach the object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx) to the context, delete it, then call `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: but in this case it permissible someone quickly double clicks, thus two potential loads and a duplicate delete.

Comment: Thank you!  This was the start of multiple issues that I had.  I will post the rest of the issues as an answer down below.